# Writing typescript Object data to file in text format

Tags: angular, typescript

```
const ObjectsToCsv = require('objects-to-csv');
 
// Sample data - two columns, three rows:
const data = [
  {code: 'CA', name: 'California'},
  {code: 'TX', name: 'Texas'},
  {code: 'NY', name: 'New York'},
];
 
// If you use "await", code must be inside an asynchronous function:
(async () => {
  const csv = new ObjectsToCsv(data);
 
  // Save to file:
  await csv.toDisk('./test.csv');
 
  // Return the CSV file as string:
  console.log(await csv.toString());
})();
```

The output of above is

```
code,name
'CA','California'
'TX','Texas'
'NY','New York'
```

I dont want to see comma as separator between elements, instead i want to choose space or tab. It looks like this package (objects-to-csv) does not provide this capability to choose different data separator other than comma.
Can anyone please let me know if there is any other package which i can use which writes above object to file without comma, or rather i can choose separator of my choice.
Or if by using above package (objects-to-csv), is there a way to not see comma and instead use space.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Heres an example, you can change the separator from comma to space - https://stackblitz.com/edit/objects-array-as-csv-cu46fy?file=csv-data.service.ts

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I looked at it, its more of writing the code ourself without using any package. I am trying to see if there is any package which does this functionality.

Comment: It seems that a PR is open for this package to provide delimiter option - https://github.com/anton-bot/objects-to-csv/pull/19

Comment: ok. Thanks for the information. I used the code you provided. Thanks for sharing the code.

Comment: Can I post that as answer?